# Launching an Activity from a Service

Tags: android

When I am trying to launch a call activity from a Service, I get a `NullPointerException`. Here is my code:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(callIntent);
```

I get the exception on the `startActivity` line.

I tried to use `getApplication.startActivity` and `getApplicationContext.startActivity` but no luck.

Any ideas?

**edit** : Maybe some usefull info:  I am trying to create a service that will run on the background and scan sensor data, when a certain signal is given i would like to maken an automated call to a number.

**edit** : full adb error code:

```
03-31 09:04:10.214: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1896): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-31 09:04:10.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1896): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service dfz.epilepsiedetector.services.DetectionService: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-31 09:04:10.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2668)
03-31 09:04:10.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3100(ActivityThread.java:116)
03-31 09:04:10.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1896):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1846)
03-31 09:04:10.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1896):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-31 09:04:10.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1896):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-31 09:04:10.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
03-31 09:04:10.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1896):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 09:04:10.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1896):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-31 09:04:10.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1896):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
03-31 09:04:10.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1896):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
03-31 09:04:10.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1896):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-31 09:04:10.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1896): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-31 09:04:10.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1896):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:120)
03-31 09:04:10.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1896):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
03-31 09:04:10.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1896):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:2302)
03-31 09:04:10.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1896):     at dfz.epilepsiedetector.services.DetectionService.<init>(DetectionService.java:35)
03-31 09:04:10.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1896):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-31 09:04:10.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1896):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1472)
03-31 09:04:10.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2665)
```

**edit** Trimmed class code:

```
public class DetectionService extends IntentService implements SensorEventListener
{   
 private SensorManager mSensorManager;
 private Sensor mAccelerometer;
 private boolean hasSeizure = false;

 private final int POLLS_PER_SECOND = 10;

 public DetectionService()
 {
 super("EpilepsionDetectionService");

 Intent callIntent = new Intent(DetectionService.this,
 InformationActivity.class);
 callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);        
 getApplication().startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

Comment: can you try ((Activity)xyz.getContext()).startActivity(it);

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by xyz?

Comment: xyz is your service; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456034/how-to-start-an-activity-from-a-service ; some guy did the same with you. do you have a permission in ANdroidManifest ?

Comment: @DO Ngoc Tuan i am calling the intent in that way, the problem is that its not working! i keep recieveing `NullPointerException`

Comment: i did the same with you before: get the value of Sensor, if(condition) call new Activity. no problem. ; - - -- - - - -                   public class MyclassService extends MapActivity implements SensorEventListener{

Comment: Yes i know, i am also able to react to sensors and launch activity's but just not from a background service, what you mention is a MapActivity. Ofcourse they both have a context but when I try to get it from the service it returns null.

Comment: MapActivity is in my situation;or you can see here , call the activity from Service, it doesnot solve your problem but it give you some idea :  - - - - -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735927/running-activity-from-remote-service

Answer (score 1):

You have to get that context from an activity where you calling a service..
from that you have to call`

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));


 callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 context.startActivity(callIntent);
```

**edit**:

```
callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplication().startActivity(callIntent);`
```

`

hope it helps...

Comment: Do you also know where i can get that context?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
getBaseContext().startActivity(callIntent);
```

Or use:

```
this.startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: @vendor Both return me a  `NullPointerException`

Comment: @nldev Can you post the full log from adb.

Comment: @vendor I posted it in the question

Comment: @nldev Do you include the right call permission in the android manifest?

Comment: @vendor Yes it all works from a normal activity, just not from the service... ?

Comment: @nldev If you code is not big, you can post it, or trim some part of it, because the above code snippet looks good to me.

Comment: @vendor I posted the code in the main question, i have a meeting now so i will be back in 1 1/2 hours

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

The problem went away when inhereting directly from Service as opposed to Intent service.

Hop this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Move the code out of the constructor and into the `onCreate()` method. The long and short of it is that the class hasn't been totally initialized yet and is causing the `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score -1):

Call the intent in the `onStart` method of the service instead of the `onCreate` method.